# Oracle unique index with condition

Tags: oracle

When I am learning oracle index, I encountered with the situation that I am not able to understand.

```
create unique index u_index1 on table_a(case when code is not null then company_id end, code)
```

I am not able to understand the purpose of this code, Does this index mean that, if code is not null then index on code, company_id is created? or if code is null then index is created on code column only? or what?

Comment: It's known as [Function-Based Index](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/indexiot.htm#CNCPT1161)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of this index(ultimately unique constraint) is:

When you insert `NULL` into `code` then uniqueness will be checked on `(NULL, CODE)`. Ok but `code` is also `NULL` so index will be on `(NULL, NULL)`. means on nothing.

When `code` is not null then index will be on `(COMPANY_ID, CODE)`

Now, let's take this in this way:
`COMPANY_ID` can have multiple duplicates with NULL `CODE` but for a single `COMAPNY_ID`, There must be a unique `CODE`

Cheers!!